# How to select subtensor from a tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor `A` with the dimension of `[N1, N2, N3/2, 2, N4, N5]`. Another tensor `B` is an boolean index tensor with the dimension of `[N1, N2, N3/2] = 1,0,0,0,1...`.
Now, I want to get a subtensor `C` with the dimension of `[N1, N2, N3/2, N4, N5]` using the index of `B` .
How could I implement this with pytorch?
Note that I don't incline to use for-loop because it is very slow.

I have looked up some functions in pytorch but found none of them are suitable for my task

Answer (score 1):

You are making no sense: How can `C` have the same `shape` as `A` when `B` only selects *part* of the entries of `A` to copy to `C`??

Suppose `B` has `k` non-zero elements (that is, `B` selects `k` elements out of `N1*N2*N3/2` matrices of size `N4*N5` in `A`) then `C` can have shape of `[k, N4, N5]` only with `k < N1*N2*N3/2`.

You can use [`nonzero()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.nonzero) to convert `B` from logical indices to `k` integer indices and then use these to select the `k` elements

```
C = A.view(-1, *A.shape[-2:])[B.nonzero(), ...]
```